# .Net Core 3 Preview SequenceReader Length Delimited Parsing

Tags: .net-core, guacamole

I'm trying to use [`SequenceReader<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.sequencereader-1?view=netcore-3.0) in .Net Core Preview 8 to parse [Guacamole Protocol](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/protocol-reference.html) network traffic.

The traffic might look as follows:

`5.error,14.some text here,1.0;`

This is a single [error instruction](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/protocol-reference.html#error-instruction). There are 3 fields:

- OpCode = `error`
- Reason = `some text here`
- Status = `0` (see [Status Codes](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/protocol-reference.html#status-codes))

The fields are comma delimited (semi-colon terminated), but they also have the length prefixed on each field. I presume that's so that you could parse something like:

`5.error,24.some, text, with, commas,1.0;`

To produce `Reason` = `some, text, with, commas`.

Simple comma delimited parsing is simple enough to do (with or without `SequenceReader`). However, to utilise the length I've tried the following:

```cs
public static bool TryGetNextElement(this ref SerializationContext context, out ReadOnlySequence<byte> element)
{
    element = default;
    var start = context.Reader.Position;
    if (!context.Reader.TryReadTo(out ReadOnlySequence<byte> lengthSlice, Utf8Bytes.Period, advancePastDelimiter: true))
        return false;
    if (!lengthSlice.TryGetInt(out var length))
        return false;
    context.Reader.Advance(length);
    element = context.Reader.Sequence.Slice(start, context.Reader.Position);
    return true;
}
```

Based on my understanding of the [initial proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32588), this should work, though also could be simplified I think because some of the methods in the proposal make life a bit easier than that which is available in .Net Core Preview 8.

However, the problem with this code is that the `SequenceReader` does not seem to `Advance` as I would expect. It's [`Position`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.sequencereader-1.position?view=netcore-3.0#System_Buffers_SequenceReader_1_Position) and [`Consumed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.sequencereader-1.consumed?view=netcore-3.0#System_Buffers_SequenceReader_1_Consumed) properties remain unchanged when advancing, so the `element` I slice at the end is *always* an empty sequence.

What do I need to do in order to parse this protocol correctly?

Comment: can I see `SerializationContext ` here? in particular, `SequenceReader<T>` is a mutable struct, so it is *really really important* to know whether `.Reader` is a *property* or a *field*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that `.Reader` here is a *property*; this is important because `SequenceReader<T>` is a *mutable struct*, but every time you access `.SomeProperty` you are working with an **isolated copy** of the reader. It is fine to hide it behind a property, but you'd need to make sure you *work with a local* and then *push back when complete*, i.e.

```cs
var reader = context.Reader;
var start = reader.Position;
if (!reader.TryReadTo(out ReadOnlySequence<byte> lengthSlice,
        Utf8Bytes.Period, advancePastDelimiter: true))
    return false;
if (!lengthSlice.TryGetInt(out var length))
    return false;
reader.Advance(length);
element = reader.Sequence.Slice(start, reader.Position);

context.Reader = reader; // update position
return true;
```

Note that a nice feature of this is that in the *failure cases* (`return false`), you *won't have changed the state yet*, because you've only been mutating your local standalone clone.

---

You *could* also consider a `ref`-return property for `.Reader`.

Comment: Awesome answer, thankyou. Still trying to fully get to grips with all the `ref`/`in`/`out`. Getting a copy makes perfect sense and explains everything. I was naively getting 4 new copies of a reader in the OP, so of course the position was always reset?

I knew I was being a lemon, just wasn't sure where! :D